# Name for sets $X$ equipped with a bijection $X \times X \cong X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, terminology

Is there a common name for pairs $(X,\alpha)$, where $X$ is a set and $\alpha : X \times X \to X$ is a bijection? Once I have heard "heap" for this, but this already has a [different meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28mathematics%29). Notice: These pairs consistute an *algebraic category*, so that there are colimits. They are not so easy to construct explicitly, though. Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: In [choiceless] set theory these are called idemmultiples. But usually that refers to the cardinal of $X$ and we are not really fussy about the bijection.

Comment: According to nLab they are called [Jónsson-Tarski algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/J%C3%B3nsson-Tarski+algebra)

Comment: @HanulJeon:  Thank you! Please make this an answer. (After all, it is the answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such objects are called [Jónsson-Tarski algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/J%C3%B3nsson-Tarski+algebra), according to nLab.

Comment: Thank you! An alternative name is Cantor algebra. There is even a Wikipedia article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B3nsson%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra

Comment: I like the term "Cantor algebra" more, since Cantor invented pairing functions (right?), and Jónsson-Tarski study these algebras only on one page, whereas Smirnov and others have several publications on Cantor algebras.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain what the nlab means with the sentence "Loosely speaking, a Jónsson-Tarski algebra is an isomorphism $2^{\aleph_0} \cong 2^{\aleph_0} \times 2^{\aleph_0}$ gone algebra."? Perhaps my English is not good enough.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg My English is also not good enough, so I just can say that it might intend the explanation given below.